# Error While deploy Web App in Tomcat

Tags: java, xml, apache, web

I have one web application in java named "**authmantra**".
When I try to deploy on tomcat7, it is giving below error.

```
Feb 4, 2014 1:08:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig parseWebXml
**SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at file:/D:/Apache/conf/web.xml**
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at

com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
    at **org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.java:1875)**
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getDefaultWebXmlFragment(ContextConfig.java:1472)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1250)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:963)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1600)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Feb 4, 2014 1:08:11 PM **org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig parseWebXml
SEVERE: Occurred at line 4285 column 2**
Feb 4, 2014 1:08:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart
SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
Feb 4, 2014 1:08:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
**SEVERE: Error getConfigured**
Feb 4, 2014 1:08:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
**SEVERE: Context [/authmantra] startup failed due to previous errors**
```

Comment: Below is my web.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            5
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>GetAuth.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>

Answer (score 0):

The semi-colons in your web-app element is causing the problem. Remove them and give it a try

Comment: I have not added semi-colons, this site have automatically added semi-colons. and my site was working fine in my old server. But when i try to deploy it on new server, it is giving error. Please note that on my new server, two other sites working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your web-app tag should be like this :

```
<web-app version="3.0" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
...
...
</web-app>
```

Comment: I have same xml that you have defined here. but this site have remove http and www words when i post it. So my web.xml is same as you defined here. Is there any other solution...?

Comment: @MaheshPatel Your xml has semicolon in it. Remove it and try again

Comment: I have not added semi-colons, this site have automatically added semi-colons. and my site was working fine in my old server. But when i try to deploy it on new server, it is giving error. Please note that on my new server, two other sites working fine.

Comment: See this link to know more
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/721237/Web-Xml-Errror-in-Tomcat